# Apache rewrite AND redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

I need some help rewriting AND redirecting as well as dealing with some old rewrite code.

in .htaccess I have some old code:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^Products[/]{0,1}$  /index.php?tabs=2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

So, as I understand it, this old code was rewriting the page so that if someone typed in http://www.example.com/Products/ it would show you the index.php?tabs=2 but the URL will actually say http://www.example.com/Products/.  However, I suppose in this case, there was no actual re-directing happening, so both pages were in existence together?

So, what I need to do now is...  I have this new working page:

```
 http://www.example.com/NewProducts.html?type=newest
```

If someone types in:

```
 http://www.example.com/NewProducts/
```

I want the new working page to show:

```
 http://www.example.com/NewProducts.html?type=newest
```

BUT i want this SEO friendly URL to show in the address bar:

```
 http://www.example.com/NewProducts/
```

And I want it to be a re-direct as well and not just a rewrite so that all in SEO land is correct.

But also, if someone types in the old URL:

```
 http://www.example.com/Products/
```

I Want that one to 301 redirect to the new SEO friendly URL of the new page:

```
 http://www.example.com/NewProducts/
```

Here is what I tried, but it is not correct:

```
 RewriteRule ^Products[/]{0,1}$  NewProducts.html?type=newest [L,QSA,NC,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^ProductsNew[/]{0,1}$  NewProducts.html?type=newest [L,QSA,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rules like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Products/?$ /NewProducts/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^NewProducts/?$ /NewProducts.html?type=newest [L,QSA,NC]
```